# Отличие в объявлении переменных, область видимости (Производительность)

Tags: javascript

Есть ли какой-то смысл, как объявлять переменные в плане производительности. Чисто логически, если подумать, то объявление переменной и её инициализация - это 2 разные операции. Есть вот такой код

```
    const mainContainer = document.querySelector('html');

    let onresize = function () {
        let width = document.querySelector('html').clientWidth;
        let containerWidth = document.querySelector('body').clientWidth;

        mainContainer.style.setProperty('--screenWidth', `${width}px`)
        mainContainer.style.setProperty('--containerWidth', `${containerWidth}px`)
    }

    window.addEventListener("resize", onresize);
    window.onload = function () {
        onresize();
    }
```

То есть, при ресайзе мы постоянно объявляем переменную и её инициализацию. Есть ли смысл в том, чтобы объявить переменную вне функции onresize и тем самым, сэкономить на производительности тем, что мы не будем постоянно её объявлять, а только менять её содержимое?

```
    const mainContainer = document.querySelector('html');

    let width, containerWidth, contentWidth;

    let onresize = function () {
        width = document.querySelector('html').clientWidth;
        containerWidth = document.querySelector('body').clientWidth;

        mainContainer.style.setProperty('--screenWidth', `${width}px`)
        mainContainer.style.setProperty('--containerWidth', `${containerWidth}px`)
    }

    window.addEventListener("resize", onresize);
    window.onload = function () {
        onresize();
    }
```

Вопрос довольно мелочный, но интересно как это всё работает в данной ситуации

Comment: Как вы думаете, вот есть у меня 100 функций и в них по 20 переменных. Имеет смысл объявить 2000 переменных сверху и потом использовать?

Comment: Эти переменные и так лежат внутри функции, они не глобальные. Я вырвал кусок из функции, которая экспортируется и компилируется в общий JS файл, тут вопрос объявление при событии

Comment: Как это отвечает на мой вопрос?))

Comment: Нет. Объявление переменной не требует времени, а вот поиск вверх по области видимости требует (движок конечно это постарается оптимизировать, но зачем делать лишнюю работу на ровном месте)

Comment: В JS лучше не занимайтесь такого рода мелочами. При компиляции js оптимизируется так, что от ваших переменных может вообще ничего не остаться.

Comment: То есть, пустые переменные сборщик мусора может снести при оптимизации?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/garbage-collection

Comment: Сборка мусора тут не при чём. Переменные существуют в вашем коде (в тексте) для вашего удобства. Но их может вообще не существовать при исполнении программы. Например адрес памяти где хранится `clientWidth` может быть сразу использован для создания строки `${width}px` или что-нибудь в этом духе.